# Create appointment with leading parenthesis

Tags: google-calendar

If I click in Google calendar (month view) and create an appointment with start time and leading parenthesis like this:

[image]

the leading parenthesis gets dropped and this is what I see in the calendar:

[image]

Is there anything that I can do to prevent this (special spacing, escape characters, ...)?

Comment: I tried using the HTML entity for a left parenthesis (`&#40;`) and it just stripped out the `&#`. I don't know why Calendar is stripping that character.

Answer (score 1):

This is bad parsing on Google's part: the code (perhaps a regular expression) that they use to extract the time and title of event from the entered string does not believe that the name of an event can begin with a non-word character. The issue is not specific to `(` - if you begin the event name with `!@#$%^&` and so on, these will all be removed.

Luckily, the [zero-width space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) is acceptable. The characters shown below include a zero-width space between the regular space and parentheses. You can copy them and use when creating events:

```
 ​(
```

For example: 9:30 ​(Car) Vet can be copy-pasted and will create an event with the correct title.

Comment: Technically a good solution, but copying that special character from here is not a solution that works in the 'real world'. Too bad.

Comment: You can look at https://superuser.com/questions/156640/ or https://superuser.com/questions/389087/ for how to type that character on a keyboard